# Using custom ruby gem with github pages throws error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, gemfile

Using custom gem with **github-pages** throws following error when running **`jekyll build`**

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:356:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'tabs (= 0.0.3) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:331:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:331:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:200:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:184:in `resolve'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'tabs', '0.0.3'
gem 'tabs-id', '0.0.1'
```

Last two gems were created by me.

And this is my ruby gem file

```
require 'kramdown'
module Tags
    class TabsBlock < Liquid::Block
        def render(context)
            content = super(context)
            content = convert(content)
        end
        def convert(context)
            liArray = context.gsub(/<li role="presentation" class="">(.+)<\/li>/)
            nextLine = "\n"
            tabOpenTag = nextLine + '<div class="tabs">' + nextLine
            ulOpenTag = nextLine + '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">' + nextLine
            tabContentOpenTag = nextLine + '<div class="tab-content">' + nextLine
            closedivTag = nextLine + '</div>' + nextLine
            ulCloseTag = nextLine + '</ul>' + nextLine
            lis = '' + nextLine
            liArray.each do|li|
                lis = lis + li + nextLine
            end     
            return tabOpenTag + ulOpenTag + lis + ulCloseTag + tabContentOpenTag +context.gsub(/<li role="presentation" class="">(.+)<\/li>/,'') + closedivTag + ulCloseTag + closedivTag
        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag("tabs", Tags::TabsBlock)
```

Comment: do those gems live on ruby gems? or are they already installed on your system?   If not you either need to install that version so bundler can find it  or provide the path in your gemfile such as `gem "tabs", :path => "/path/to/gem"`

Comment: Yes. Those gems were already in live. I've tried the path method also. But result is same

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use any additional ruby gems in Github Pages other than the gem `github-pages`.

You Gemfile should read:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/

Comment: One way to get around this is to build the site locally and commit the output to a different branch or repo.

Comment: @RossPhillips Yup! you could easily integrate travis-ci do auto-deploy to a specific branch if more specific gems are needed